# Upside down right triangle in Java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I need to do this:

```
*****
 ****
  ***
   **
    *
```

and I have this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            for (int j=5; j>i; j--)
            {    
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
```

which outputs this:

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I cant figure out how to implement the spaces. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use two for-loops: one for the number of spaces and one for the number of `*`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {    
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    for (int j = i; j < 5; j++) {    
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Java 8 solution:

```
IntStream.range(0, 5).forEach(i -> {
    IntStream.range(0, i).forEach(j -> System.out.print(" "));
    IntStream.range(i, 5).forEach(j -> System.out.print("*"));
    System.out.println();
});
```

Comment: You had been faster, I was writting the same :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution with one less loop than the other answers, if you really want to wow the person who's grading your assignment:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++) {
        System.out.print((x >= y) ? "*" : " ");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Anyone wants to show their answer by using only one loop? XD It can be done though (without using strings & recursion).

Comment: @user3437460 I can do you one better: an answer with zero loops! `System.out.print("*****\n_****\n__***\n___**\n____*\n");`. I doubt that's what the assignment was about though.

Comment: No haha, I mean by obeying the rules - printing the triangle with only `System.out.print("*")` and `System.out.println()` and no other ways to print should be allowed.

Comment: [Here you go, zero loops.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/636aa226e2b7354e9374)

Comment: What about a size n triangle? hehe

Comment: You're a difficult customer to please, @user3437460 :)

Comment: That day someone asked me to code with -1 loops. Just kidding, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Just print `k` number of spaces before start of every line.

To solve this kind of problems, it will be easy if you break it down and observe the pattern.

```
*****  0 space
 ****  1 space
  ***  2 spaces
   **  3 spaces
    *  4 spaces
```

After taking note of this pattern, you ask yourself will you be able to print this?

```
0*****
1****
2***
3**
4*
```

We see that the number is similar to the start of every line. Hence we could make use of variable i. (your outer loop counter) and we have..

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    System.out.println(i);
    for (int j=5; j>i; j--){ 
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Now, you just have to convert your numbers at the start of every line to the number of spaces and you have..

```
for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
    for(int k=0; k<i; k++)    //using i to control number of spaces
        System.out.println(" ");
    for (int j=5; j>i; j--){ 
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: I think there is no changes with the first one answer.

Comment: @Error404 I did not copy his. Anyway more importantly I want OP to learn how to tackle this kind of problem.

Comment: Sure, it is also important to explain the method that you need to get it. I suppose that you didn't copy it (I was going to put the same answer xD) but in your first post I didn't see a lot of changes with the other answer. Just was a point ;)

Comment: @Error404 sure ;) Actually there are a lot more possible solutions. It can even be done with one loop. But I give what his school teacher expect from them.

Comment: True story. Also I think that using two loops it's the best way to learn and clarify at the begining. Happy coding ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int count = 6;
    for(int i=0; i<=count; i++) {

        for(int j=0; j<i; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j <= (count - i); j ++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
```

you can pass your value into count, its works pretty nice.