# Can't print the pattern

Tags: java

I created the code that should print a pattern like

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
```

I have the code written below, the logic works fine in python but in java the output is different.

```
class Testing{
    public static void main(String args[])
    { 
        for (int i = 1; i<6;i++)
        {

            for (int j =0; j<i-1;j++)
                { 
                System.out.print(" ");
                }
                while (i < 6){ 
                    System.out.print(k);
                    System.out.println(); 
                    i++;
                } 
        }
    }
}
```

The output is just `12345`. I don't understand why does it iterate over first for loop for only once.

Comment: Because you're incrementing `i` in your while loop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260163/upside-down-right-triangle-in-java

Comment: you try above link that has what you expect.

Comment: if not incremented it would lead to infinite loop. Just for information this logic works in python but not in java

Comment: @KumaresanPerumal I know there are answers on how to implement this pattern but i want to know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: @AyushVerma put sysout log. find out the solution.

Comment: @AyushVerma I wrote this program for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another variable for `while` control.

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int k;
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            k = i;
            while (k < 6) {
                System.out.print(k);
                k++;
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see this in this [link](http://ideone.com/gG9CIy)

this will show you :

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
```

Comment: no @AyushVerma i don't cheat if you checked the link it was correct from the beginning, so instead to copie past it, i write it manually for that i makes that mistake did you understand now, this message for you and for frederick99 ok why i should to cheat haha this is a simple problem

Comment: who even said that.. :D @YCF_L

Comment: frederick99 i edit your answer and you appreciate the up-vote so i hope you accept this

Comment: because @AyushVerma said i'm a cheater in the comment **damn this thing is crazy. I think frederick99 you should get the answer vote** ok good luck he really make me angry whatever you appreciate the 10+15 point good luck

Comment: O.o wow! i din't know he said that. You hav 3.7k reps. Why'd you need to copy from me? xD

Comment: @YCF_L why so serious. Now we should stop this else someone senior would come and ban us both.

Comment: at least you can say i'm sorry @RahulKhanna whatever go in your way please

Answer (score 0):

Note: When 'while loop' increases. That increases i value bigger than 6. So next time it terminates the outer loop. That was your mistake.

package com.appointment.api;

```
class Testing {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            System.out.println();
            for (int j = 0; j < i - 1; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            int x = i;
            while (x < 5) {
                System.out.print(i);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks man. i explained what you did in your program please have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Following is a [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) implementation of the problem:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, MAX)
                    .mapToObj(j -> j == MAX ? j + "\n" : j >= i ? j : " ")
                    .forEach(System.out::print)
            );
```

Set `MAX = 5` and it will print your pattern.

Output:

```
12345
 2345
  345
   45
    5
```